# Convert audio to frequency array and back to audio in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, fft

I'm trying to convert musical notes to frequency domain, scale it and generate new notes in React. In below code, I just tried to reconvert the frequency array to original audio file.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import FFT from 'fft.js';
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

const AudioProcessor = () => {
  const [audioBuffer, setAudioBuffer] = useState(null);
  const [sampleRate, setSampleRate] = useState(null);

  const loadAudioFile = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('./audio.wav');
      const arrayBuffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
      const audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
      const decodedAudio = await audioCtx.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer);
      setAudioBuffer(decodedAudio.getChannelData(0));
      setSampleRate(decodedAudio.sampleRate);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const processAudio = () => {
    if (!audioBuffer || !sampleRate) {
      return;
    }

    const fft = new FFT(1024, sampleRate);
    const spectrum = fft.createComplexArray();
    const signal = fft.createComplexArray();

    // compute FFT with phase and amplitude
    fft.realTransform(spectrum, audioBuffer);
    fft.completeSpectrum(spectrum);

    // compute IFFT to reconstruct the audio signal
    fft.inverseTransform(signal, spectrum);
    const reconstructedAudio = fft.fromComplexArray(signal).map((x) => x / audioBuffer.length);

    // create audio context and buffer source
    const audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
    const audioPlayer = audioCtx.createBufferSource();

    // create audio buffer from reconstructed audio
    const reconstructedAudioBuffer = audioCtx.createBuffer(1, reconstructedAudio.length, sampleRate);
    reconstructedAudioBuffer.getChannelData(0).set(reconstructedAudio);

    // play reconstructed audio
    audioPlayer.buffer = reconstructedAudioBuffer;
    audioPlayer.connect(audioCtx.destination);
    audioPlayer.volume = 0.5;
    audioPlayer.start(0);

    // save reconstructed audio to file
    const blob = new Blob([new Float32Array(reconstructedAudio).buffer], { type: 'audio/wav' });
    saveAs(blob, 'reconstructed_audio.wav');
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={loadAudioFile}>Load Audio File</button>
      <button onClick={processAudio}>Process Audio</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AudioProcessor;
```

However, reconstructed audio is corrupted and not playable. What are the changes I should make in the above code to properly reconstruct the audio?